# How to Validate InputQuery user input before the user clicks OK?

Tags: validation, delphi, user-input, delphi-11-alexandria

In a 32-bit VCL Application in Windows 10 in Delphi 11 Alexandria, I show an INPUT DIALOG to the user:

```
  var aNewFolderName: string := 'New Project Folder';
  if Vcl.Dialogs.InputQuery('New Project Folder', 'Enter the name of the new Project Folder:', aNewFolderName) then
  begin
    // Todo: Create the folder if everything went OK, ELSE REPEAT the input action :-(
  end;
```

Is there a way to VALIDATE the user's input BEFORE he clicks the OK button? (E.g., checking for not allowed characters, existing folder, etc.). Just repeating the whole input action in the case of invalid input AFTER the user clicked OK is not very smart and efficient:

```
  var aNewFolderName: string := 'New Project Folder';
  var InputIsValid: Boolean;
  repeat
    if Vcl.Dialogs.InputQuery('New Project Folder', 'Enter the name of the new Project Folder:', aNewFolderName) then
    begin
      InputIsValid := CheckInput(aNewFolderName);
      if InputIsValid then CreateTheFolder(aNewFolderName);
    end
    else
      BREAK;
  until InputIsValid;
```

Also, with this method, there is no feedback for the user about the specific cause of any invalid input.

Comment: No, there is no designed way to validate `InputQuery` user input before they press OK.

Comment: Have you seen my old https://specials.rejbrand.se/dev/classes/multiinput/readme.html?

Comment: Why are you using `InputQuery()` to ask the user for a folder path? You should use a system dialog that is actually designed for that purpose, like`SHBrowseForFolder()`, or `TFileOpenDialog` with the `fdoPickFolders` option.

Answer (score 4):

Although it is possible to solve this problem by using repeated dialogs, I don't think that is a particularly elegant solution from a UX perspective.

I'd rather make my own dialog and do something like this:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.btnSetPasswordClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var psw := '';
  if SuperInput(
    Self,
    'Frog Simulator',
    'Please enter the new frog password:',
    psw,
    function(const Text: string; out AErrorMessage: string): Boolean
    begin
      if Text.Length < 8 then
      begin
        AErrorMessage := 'The password''s length must be at least 8 characters.';
        Exit(False);
      end;
      if not StrHasChrOfType(Text, TCharacter.IsLetter) then
      begin
        AErrorMessage := 'The password must contain at least one letter.';
        Exit(False);
      end;
      if not StrHasChrOfType(Text, TCharacter.IsDigit) then
      begin
        AErrorMessage := 'The password must contain at least one digit.';
        Exit(False);
      end;
      if not StrHasChrOfType(Text, TCharacter.IsPunctuation) then
      begin
        AErrorMessage := 'The password must contain at least one punctuation character.';
        Exit(False);
      end;
      Result := True;
    end)
  then
    lblNewPassword.Caption := psw;
end;
```

[image: Screen recording of this "Super Input Dialog" in action, validating my passoword at real time.]

Here's the code:

```pascal
unit SuperInputDlg;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TValidator = reference to function(const Text: string;
    out AErrorMessage: string): Boolean;
  TSuperInputForm = class(TForm)
    lblCaption: TLabel;
    shClient: TShape;
    Edit: TEdit;
    pbErrorIcon: TPaintBox;
    lblError: TLabel;
    Validator: TTimer;
    btnOK: TButton;
    btnCancel: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure pbErrorIconPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure EditChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ValidatorTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnOKClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FErrorIcon: HICON;
    FLIWSD: Boolean;
    FValidator: TValidator;
    function DoValidate: Boolean;
  public
  end;

function SuperInput(AOwnerForm: TCustomForm; const ACaption, AMainInstruction: string;
  var AText: string; AValidator: TValidator = nil): Boolean;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function Scale(X: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := MulDiv(X, Screen.PixelsPerInch, 96);
end;

procedure TSuperInputForm.btnOKClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if DoValidate then
    ModalResult := mrOK;
end;

function TSuperInputForm.DoValidate: Boolean;
begin

  var LErrMsg: string;
  var LIsValid := not Assigned(FValidator) or FValidator(Edit.Text, LErrMsg);

  btnOK.Enabled := LIsValid;

  if not LIsValid then
    lblError.Caption := LErrMsg;

  pbErrorIcon.Visible := not LIsValid;
  lblError.Visible := not LIsValid;

  Result := LIsValid;

end;

procedure TSuperInputForm.EditChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Validator.Enabled := False;
  Validator.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TSuperInputForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ComCtl: HMODULE;
  LoadIconWithScaleDown: function(hinst: HINST; pszName: LPCWSTR; cx: Integer;
    cy: Integer; var phico: HICON): HResult; stdcall;
begin

  ComCtl := LoadLibrary('ComCtl32.dll');
  if ComCtl <> 0 then
  begin
    try
      LoadIconWithScaleDown := GetProcAddress(ComCtl, 'LoadIconWithScaleDown');
      if Assigned(LoadIconWithScaleDown) then
        LoadIconWithScaleDown(0, IDI_ERROR, Scale(16), Scale(16), FErrorIcon);
    finally
      FreeLibrary(ComCtl);
    end;
  end;

  FLIWSD := FErrorIcon <> 0;
  if FErrorIcon = 0 then
    FErrorIcon := LoadIcon(0, IDI_ERROR);

end;

procedure TSuperInputForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FLIWSD then
    DestroyIcon(FErrorIcon);
end;

procedure TSuperInputForm.pbErrorIconPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FErrorIcon <> 0 then
    DrawIconEx(pbErrorIcon.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, FErrorIcon,
      Scale(16), Scale(16), 0, 0, DI_NORMAL);
end;

procedure TSuperInputForm.ValidatorTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoValidate;
end;

function SuperInput(AOwnerForm: TCustomForm; const ACaption, AMainInstruction: string;
  var AText: string; AValidator: TValidator = nil): Boolean;
begin
  var LFrm := TSuperInputForm.Create(AOwnerForm);
  try
    LFrm.Caption := ACaption;
    LFrm.lblCaption.Caption := AMainInstruction;
    LFrm.Edit.Text := AText;
    LFrm.FValidator := AValidator;
    LFrm.DoValidate;
    Result := LFrm.ShowModal = mrOk;
    if Result then
      AText := LFrm.Edit.Text;
  finally
    LFrm.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

and DFM:

```pascal
object SuperInputForm: TSuperInputForm
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Input Box'
  ClientHeight = 166
  ClientWidth = 469
  Color = clBtnFace
  Constraints.MaxHeight = 204
  Constraints.MinHeight = 204
  Constraints.MinWidth = 400
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -12
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poOwnerFormCenter
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnDestroy = FormDestroy
  DesignSize = (
    469
    166)
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 15
  object shClient: TShape
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 468
    Height = 127
    Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom]
    Pen.Style = psClear
    ExplicitWidth = 499
    ExplicitHeight = 175
  end
  object lblCaption: TLabel
    Left = 24
    Top = 24
    Width = 65
    Height = 21
    Caption = 'Input Box'
    Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Font.Color = 10040064
    Font.Height = -16
    Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
    Font.Style = []
    ParentFont = False
  end
  object pbErrorIcon: TPaintBox
    Left = 24
    Top = 88
    Width = 16
    Height = 16
    OnPaint = pbErrorIconPaint
  end
  object lblError: TLabel
    Left = 50
    Top = 88
    Width = 3
    Height = 15
  end
  object Edit: TEdit
    Left = 24
    Top = 51
    Width = 418
    Height = 23
    Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight]
    TabOrder = 0
    OnChange = EditChange
    ExplicitWidth = 449
  end
  object btnOK: TButton
    Left = 286
    Top = 133
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Anchors = [akRight, akBottom]
    Caption = 'OK'
    Default = True
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = btnOKClick
    ExplicitLeft = 317
    ExplicitTop = 181
  end
  object btnCancel: TButton
    Left = 367
    Top = 133
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Anchors = [akRight, akBottom]
    Cancel = True
    Caption = 'Cancel'
    ModalResult = 2
    TabOrder = 2
    ExplicitLeft = 398
    ExplicitTop = 181
  end
  object Validator: TTimer
    OnTimer = ValidatorTimer
    Left = 136
    Top = 120
  end
end
```

Please note that this is only a sketch I did in ten minutes -- in a real app, you'd spend a bit more time on this one.

**Appendix 1**

```pascal
type
  TChrTestFcn = function(C: Char): Boolean;

function StrHasChrOfType(const AText: string; ATestFcn: TChrTestFcn): Boolean;
begin
  for var S in AText do
    if ATestFcn(S) then
      Exit(True);
  Result := False;
end;
```

Comment: Nice. I like frogs!

Comment: [Password complexity is an outdated approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength#Common_guidelines), tho - it actually weakens strength in contrast to e.g. just increasing the length.

Comment: @AmigoJack: Yes, the main point of my answer is to demonstrate the input dialog UX; the password thing was merely an example. I chose that particular example because it is familiar to (almost) everyone and naturally gave me an opportunity to show that input validation can be made in real time, with visual feedback, in a truly context-sensitive way. I didn't mean to promote this approach to choosing passwords. Also, this particular example is suboptimal in another way: it doesn't tell the user the full requirements of the password. If you enter `aldosterone` and are told that you must have a...

Comment: ...digit, you may come up with `3141592653589` instead, only to later on be told you need some punctuation. "Gah... Why didn't you tell me that from the beginning!"

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most versatile option is to write your own input dialog and either include the validation code in the dialog or alternatively pass a callback method that does the validation.

But to answer the question as you asked it:

"Is there a way to VALIDATE the user's input BEFORE he clicks the OK button?"

No, there is no way, as far as I know.

Comment: Sure. But my question was implicitly asking whether there is an EXISTING way to validate the user input. When asking, e.g., how to find the railway station, you answer 'Build your own railway station'? Or is your answer implicitly saying there is no existing railway station in town?

Comment: I made a trivial example of this.

Comment: @user1580348 There is a big difference between something as complex as a railway station and an input dialog for a single line of text and two buttons. The latter can be created within half a minute. And if you follow my hint regarding a callback method for the validation, it can be re-used for arbitrary kinds of input. But you are right: The answer to your question is "No", at least as far as I know. I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way. But there are alternatives:

1. Look up `InputQuery`'s code, write similar code and then make modifications where you want them (e.g. setting an `OnChange` handler for the `TEdit`). You'll notice it has been done in a quite simple way.
2. Design your own form for it, instead of (like `InputQuery` does) creating one on the fly:

   - You can either use your own logic for getting the user's choice and input when the form is closed, or
   - you set the form's `ModalResult` property (via code) anytime, and you can assign a `ModalResult` to each button (e.g. `mrCancel`), so it automatically sets the form's `ModalResult` property. Call your own form just as if it's [`MessageBox()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.MessageBox):

     ```delphi
     case MyForm.ShowModal() of
       IDOK: begin
         // User wants to proceed AND no error was found
       end;
       IDCANCEL: begin
         // User gave up
       end;
     else
       // Unexpected result
     end;
     ```
3. For me it would make nearly no difference if any feedback is given with any form still visible or not, as long as it is given. And you can give it, because nothing keeps you from doing so:

   ```delphi
   var 
     aNewFolderName,
     sErrorMsg: String;
   begin
     repeat
       aNewFolderName:= 'New Project Folder';

       // User cancelled: leaving loop
       if not Vcl.Dialogs.InputQuery( 'New project folder', 'Enter the name of the new project folder:', aNewFolderName ) then break;

       // Already errors before the attempt?
       sErrorMsg:= CheckInput( aNewFolderName );

       // Actual attempt, which may still go wrong for various reasons
       if sErrorMsg= '' then sErrorMsg:= CreateTheFolder( aNewFolderName );

       // Anything to report?
       if sErrorMsg<> '' then begin
         sErrorMsg:= sErrorMsg+ #13#10
         + 'Click "Retry" to try a different new project name.'+ #13#10
         + 'Click "Cancel" to not create any new project.';
         if MessageBox( sErrorMsg, 'Error', MB_RETRYCANCEL )= IDCANCEL then break;
       end else begin
         break;  // Otherwise we're done (CreateTheFolder was successful)
       end;
     until FALSE;
   end;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the users who explicitly confirmed that there is no predesigned way to validate the input before the user clicks OK. Now the remaining question is: How to provide a meaningful and efficient feedback about the invalidation cause to the user? IMO, showing an ADDITIONAL error dialog does not meet these criteria. So I implemented a solution where the prompt is replaced by the validation error message in the reappearing InputQuery dialog:

```
procedure TformMain.menuitemCreateASubProjectGroupClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var aNewFolderName: string := 'New Project Group';
  var InputIsValid: Boolean;
  var InputPrompt: string := 'Enter the name of the new Project Group:';
  repeat
    if Vcl.Dialogs.InputQuery('New Project Group', InputPrompt, aNewFolderName) then
    begin
      var NewPrompt: string;
      InputIsValid := CheckInput(aNewFolderName, NewPrompt);
      if not InputIsValid then
        InputPrompt := NewPrompt
      else
      begin
        CreateNewFolder(aNewFolderName);
      end;
    end
    else
      BREAK;
  until InputIsValid;
end;

function PAIsFilenameValid(const AFilename: string; var errorchar: Char): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;

  for var i := 1 to Length(AFilename) do
  begin
    if not System.IOUtils.TPath.IsValidFileNameChar(AFilename[i]) then
    begin
      errorchar := AFilename[i];
      Result := False;
      BREAK;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TformMain.CheckInput(const aNewFolderName: string; out aNewPrompt: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  var errorchar: Char;
  if Trim(aNewFolderName) = '' then
  begin
    aNewPrompt := 'Error: You must enter a Group name:';
    Result := False;
  end
  else if not PAIsFilenameValid(aNewFolderName, errorchar) then
  begin
    aNewPrompt := 'Error: No illegal characters (' + errorchar + '):';
    Result := False;
  end;
  // Todo: else...
end;
```

Example screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you insist on using InputQuery for this?

Comment: "_No illegal characters_" alone is the opposite meaning of "_No illegal characters **allowed**_" and thus a misleading message. Why not "_Illegal character found_"?

Comment: @AmigoJack Obviously you don't understand the semantic meaning of the colon character (:).

Comment: I do; also I'd never use it twice - caption or not.